# Can't launch applications after uninstalling theme

Tags: themes, icon-themes, gnome-tweaks

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 with GNOME environment. I'm not very experienced in Linux. I was just customizing my desktop by installing themes, icon packs, etc. using gnome tweaks tool.

I was using a material theme alongside with Communitheme (Yaru) icons but on Ubuntu session (not on communitheme session). Then after uninstalling communitheme and logging out and in, my icons are gone and I can't launch most of the applications including terminal, file manager, gnome tweak tool.

I tried to remove gnome tweak tool from <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> command line but that didn't work. Is there a way to disable themes temporarily so I can pick another theme from tweak tool?

Here is a screenshot:
[image: icons are gone]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reset icon theme by pressing Alt+F2 and entering this code: `gsettings reset org.gnome.desktop.interface icon-theme`. then all the icons came back. Now I can start the apps.